# Are the master and worker nodes the same node in case of a single node cluster?

Tags: kubernetes, cluster-computing, minikube

I started a minikube cluster (single node cluster) on my local machine with the command:

```
minikube start --driver=virtualbox
```

Now, when I execute the command:

```
kubectl get nodes
```

it returns:

```
 NAME       STATUS   ROLES    AGE     VERSION 
minikube    Ready   master   2m59s    v1.19.0
```

My question is: since the cluster has only one node and according to the previous command it is a master node, what is the worker node? Are the master and worker nodes the same node in case of a single node cluster?

Comment: Short answer : yes. 

Note that in K8S, masters ARE nodes, they simply have some specific taints and tolerations (https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/scheduling-eviction/taint-and-toleration/) that restrict the kind of pods they are allowed to hosts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> since the cluster has only one node and according to the previous command it is a master node, what is the worker node? Are the master and worker nodes the same node in case of a single node cluster?

Yes, using Minikube, you only use a single node. And your workload is scheduled to execute on the same node.

Typically, [Taints and Tolerations](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/scheduling-eviction/taint-and-toleration/) is used on master nodes to prevent workload to be scheduled to those nodes.

Answer (score 2):

The answer to your question is yes in your case your master node is itself a worker node.

`Cluster` The group of vm or physical computers.

`Master` is the where control plane component installed such as etcd,controller-manager,api-server which are necessary to control the whole cluster state. In best practices and big production cluster never ever use master node to schedule application related workload.

`Worker node` is the simple plane VM where docker and kubernetes packages installed but not installed the control-plane component etc. Normally worker node is used to handle your application related workload.

> And if you have only one machine where you configure kubernetes then it becomes single node kubernetes. and it act as a master/worker.

I hope this helps you to unsderstand